# (React Native) How to set margin or padding or width or height?

Tags: react-native

`<View style={width: 20}>Hello</View>`

Platform.OS ?

Dimensions.get("screen") ?
-> 1100, 1440 ... ?

How to separate width?
I want it to look the same on all devices, both Android and iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set responsive `width`, or the `width` that varies with the device `width`, use `Dimension`. Take a look at the following code:

```
import {Dimension, StyleSheet} from 'react-native`

.....
<View style={styles.container}>Hello</View>
.....

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container:{
          width: Dimension.get('screen').width, // the container will take the whole width of the device screen width
       }
 })
```

**If you are answered let me know**

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to get Platform information for making a responsive UI.
You can simply import `"Dimensions"` and get width from it.

Example :

```
import {Dimension} from "react-native"

//for width
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

//for height
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
```